# Mesos ExamplesTest.PythonFramework check fails on OSX

Tags: python, macos, gcc, osx-mavericks, mesos

After successfully compiling Mesos 0.16.0, running the tests fails when checking the PythonFramework. All other tests pass successfully.

---

Steps I used for building:

```
./bootstrap
mkdir build
cd build
../configure CXX=g++4.7 CC=gcc-4.7
make
```

---

Then, when running the tests;

```
make check
```

The results look like this:

```
[...]
[ RUN      ] ExamplesTest.PythonFramework
../../src/tests/script.cpp:78: Failure
Failed
python_framework_test.sh exited with status 1
[  FAILED  ] ExamplesTest.PythonFramework (201 ms)
[...]
```

---

Environment:

> OS X 10.9.1 (Mavericks)
>
> Python 2.7.5 (default, Aug 25 2013, 00:04:04)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible
> Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)] on darwin
>
> gcc-4.7 (GCC) 4.7.3 Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
> This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There
> is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
> PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

---

**How do I build proper Mesos Python bindings that pass the tests within this environment?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:**

My former answer has mostly become obsolete as of Mesos 0.17.0 due to the fact that this version does fully handle clang compilage (Yay!). So there is no need to compile it using gcc anymore - just go ahead and use Xcode's clang (Xcode commandline utilities).

In case you still get into trouble getting the Python bindings to work, please add a comment or new question here on StackOverflow or post into the Mesos Mailing list.

---

**Mesos version 0.16.0 or lower:**

How to fix the Python bindings of Mesos on OS X (10.9).

**Install Python 2.7.3 via homebrew**

Find out which versions are available

`brew versions python`

> 2.7.6    git checkout 3c86d2b /usr/local/Library/Formula/python.rb
>
> 2.7.5    git checkout a04b443 /usr/local/Library/Formula/python.rb
>
> **2.7.3    git checkout 865f763 /usr/local/Library/Formula/python.rb**
>
> 2.7.4    git checkout 280581d /usr/local/Library/Formula/python.rb
>
> [...]

Select Python 2.7.3

`cd /usr/local/Library/Formula/`

`git checkout 865f763 /usr/local/Library/Formula/python.rb`

`brew install python`

Make sure you do not force installing a universal build (32 + 64bit) as that would again cause the same issue explained below. The default is 64bit only and that is just fine.

---

**Rebuild Mesos in connection with your custom Python installation**

`rm -rf build`

`rm -rf ~/.python-eggs`

`mkdir build`

`cd build`

`../configure CXX=g++-4.7 CC=gcc-4.7 PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python`

`make`

`make check`

---

You should now see a properly functioning test, hence a perfectly fine Mesos Python binding:

> [ RUN      ] ExamplesTest.PythonFramework
>
> [       OK ] ExamplesTest.PythonFramework (1682 ms)

---

As asking users to install a custom Python version often is just wrong but in this case appears to be inevitable, let me draft an explanation of the issue. And maybe one of the readers knows a better workaround.

Manually executing that test using the verbosive output setting does help identifying the exact problem.

`bin/mesos-tests.sh --gtest_filter="*.PythonFramework" --verbose`

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/till/Documents/Development/github/mesos-master/build/../src/examples/python/test_framework.py",
>   line 23, in 
>       import mesos   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/mesos.py", line 26, in    File
>   "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/_mesos.py", line 7, in 
>   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.9-intel/egg/_mesos.py", line 6, in
>   **bootstrap** ImportError: dlopen(/Users/till/.python-eggs/mesos-0.16.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg-tmp/_mesos.so,
>   2): Symbol not found: __ZNSoD0Ev   Referenced from:
>   /Users/till/.python-eggs/mesos-0.16.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg-tmp/_mesos.so
>   Expected in: flat namespace  in
>   /Users/till/.python-eggs/mesos-0.16.0-py2.7-macosx-10.9-intel.egg-tmp/_mesos.so

The important detail is the fact that the dynamic linkage of that native Python egg failed.

The reasoning is to be found within the `distutils` build step of this module when building mesos 0.16. The Python `distutils` derive their build-settings directly from `python-config`. As your Python was built using `clang`, the `distutils` will try to build your native egg using `clang` as well.

Issues:

- Mesos' autoconf phase did not propagate the compiler settings into the `distutils` build phase. So even though Mesos itself is being built using gcc-4.7 in the above description, the egg is being built using clang. The result is a mishmash of libc++ and stdlibc++ which are not  ABI compatible.

  - that part is being fixed right now, Mesos will use the same compiler in the `distutils` build phase as well (see [MESOS-798](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-798) and [MESOS-799](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-799)). Chances are pretty high that when you read this answer, that particular issue was already taken care of.
- The default OS X Python `distutils` do enforce building universal binaries (i386 + x86_64) using parameters that only the gcc-frontend of clang supports. There appears to be no workaround, hence all dynamically linked dependencies of that egg will have to be built for both architectures as well (this appears to be a leftover from OS X 10.6).
- Mesos itself is linked statically into that egg, hence it does not have to be built as a  universal binary for the egg to build and function on a 64bit platform. It will however fail to execute on a 32bit platform.
- As long as Mesos does not support clang compilage (hence being linked against libc++), the only proper workaround seems to be to install a differently compiled Python. A quick and easy solution is using `homebrew` to install Python 2.7.3. **Note**: do not install Python 2.7.6 (the current default of homebrew) as that one has issues in connection with its autoconf developer macro (see [MESOS-617](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-617))

---